# Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent

I have set an intent on a list item so that when I click the item a new activity starts. My app crashes when I click on the list item and this message is displayed in the logcat:

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0c0055 (com.example.android.sunshine:id/container) for fragment DetailFragment{470791f #0 id=0x7f0c0055}**

Here is the detail fragment the message is reffering to:

```
public static class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public DetailFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

        // The detail Activity called via intent.  Inspect the intent for forecast data.
        Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
        if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            String forecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                    .setText(forecastStr);
        }
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Make sure that the `fragment_detail` file contains the `detail_text` text view.

Comment: Yup, the fragment_detail file contains the detail_text text view.

Comment: you should try to clear cache and rebuild it. I've met this error many times.

Comment: show your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly getting String value from intent, 
try to get String value from Bundle, like the example below, you are getting **Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found** because it is getting crash before returning the view to the fragment.

```
Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
if (intent != null && intent.getExtras()!= null) {
    String forecastStr = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "");
    ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                    .setText(forecastStr);
}
```